# Using a dict as decorators on python

Tags: python, function, decorator, wrapper

There some way to use a ***dict*** as a decorator on python using the default **"@"** syntax?

Like something like:

```py
from functools import wraps
def deco(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("WRAPPER")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

X={ "deco": deco }

# Working
@deco
def f():
    pass

# Not Working: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
@X["deco"]
def y():
    pass

f()
y()
```

If change to use ***get()*** on the **dict**, this work, but something like this dont:

```py
# Not working: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
@X.get("deco").require(http_exception=403)
def y():
    pass
```

There some way for this syntax work or/and why not working?

Comment: Interesting edge cases you found there. I have no idea what your second code block is supposed to be doing though...there's no `.require()` function *inside* your decorator function (which seems like a rather weird thing anyways)...

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I have a dict with all permissions, and the decorator is on .require(), for example. I can make another dict or not use a dict, but is more clear making a dict, i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax was intentionally restricted.  See [PEP-0318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax):

> The decorator statement is limited in what it can accept -- arbitrary
>   expressions will not work. Guido preferred this because of a [gut feeling](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-August/046711.html).
>
> The current syntax also allows decorator declarations to call a
>   function that returns a decorator:

The [email the PEP links](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-August/046711.html) says:

> I have a gut feeling about this one.  I'm not sure where it comes
>   from, but I have it.  It may be that I want the compiler to be able to
>   recognize certain decorators.
>
> So while it would be quite easy to change the syntax to @test in the
>   future, I'd like to stick with the more restricted form unless a real
>   use case is presented where allowing @test would increase readability.
>   (@foo().bar() doesn't count because I don't expect you'll ever need
>   that).

So the creator/lead contributor to the language decided that allowing any expression to serve as a decorator would lead to difficult to read code.

It's also never necessary.  You can always do

```
my_deco = X.get("deco").require(http_exception=403)
@my_deco
def somefunc():
    ...
```

Comment: python ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. This syntax is how i make the code now, but this is unnecessary coding. But, this is a answer of why i cannot do.